# If an object falls from outer space on the Earth has the Coriolis effect always an influence?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, quantum-gravity

Due to the rotation of the Earth objects on Earth tend to deviate a bit from their initial direction. But imagine a meteorite is encountering the Earth does it always deflects a bit due to the Coriolis effect?

And does it make a difference whether the object is encountering straight at the equator or just above or beneath it? Does it deflect on the equator only to the left or right and at other places also to the north or south?

Answer (score 1):

The coreolis effect is an effect caused by implementing your equations of motion in a rotating frame.  In general when we're thinking about meteors, we're thinking in a non-rotating frame because the motion of celestial bodies is simplest in a non-rotating frame.  The meteor will fall "straight down" in that frame.

An individual on the Earth looking up at that meteor would perceive a Coreolis effect acting on the meteor because that individual is thinking from the perspective of a rotating frame.

Answer (score 0):

As seen by an outside observer the object will "fall" radially inwards with *no* sideways deviation, while the earth is spinning underneath it.

Why? Because coriolis forces are not real forces. From the point of view of an earth observer it is the observer that deviates and not the object.